# How to configure nginx so that my app doesn't need to have the port in the url?

Tags: nginx, digital-ocean, droplet

I have a droplet on digitalOcean and I setup my app there via docker. I have also connected it to a domain and it runs when I go to wwww.myDomain.com:3000.

I want to get rid of the "3000" part and during research I found nginx which I am trying to configure. The problem I have been facing is that I have found alot of articles but none of them give me a straight answer.

I connected to my ubuntu on digitalOcean and I am here right now:

```
#
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/myDomain.com;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _; myDomain.com

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    #       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #       deny all;
    #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#       listen 80;
#       listen [::]:80;
#
#       server_name example.com;
#
#       root /var/www/example.com;
#       index index.html;
#
```

Which is the template. I have changed the serverName and root to "myDomain.com" but as far as the rest Im a bit over my head as of now and I honestly don't know what more to change to get this to work.

The next step is to setup SSL but I need some help geting this right and perhaps a link or two to some good tutorials/articles.